# Check differences in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I have a set of arrays that can be different every time. the below one contains and array with more arrays inside them which wont be of the same size.
I need to loop through each array and check if there is any difference between them.
So with the given array all the possible combinations are as follow:

```
array_diff($arrays[0][0],$arrays[1][0]);
array_diff($arrays[0][1],$arrays[1][1]);
array_diff($arrays[0][1],$arrays[1][2]);


$arrays = [
0 => [
  0 =>  [
     9 => "39"
     10 => "40"
     14 => "62"
  ]
  1 =>  [
     9 => "38"
     10 => "40"
     14 => "63"
  ]
]
1 => [
   0 => [
     9 => "39"
     10 => "40"
     14 => "62"
  ]
  1 =>  [
     9 => "39"
     10 => "40"
     14 => "64"
  ]
  2 =>  [
     9 => "39"
     10 => "41"
     14 => "62"
  ]
]
]
```

This is what I am trying:

```
foreach($combinations as $set_id => $comb)
    {
        foreach($comb as $key => $selections)
        {

            if(isset($combinations[++$set_id][$key])){
                if(!empty(array_diff($selections, $combinations[++$set_id][$key]))){
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

I want to know if same array is contained in another array. Can you see from my example that array[0] and array[1] contain different combinations of arrays. So if one of the combinations are exactly the same i need to display an error.

In this case array_diff($arrays[0][0],$arrays[1][0]); should return an empty array which means there are no difference and I should display and error.

Comment: Always tag the specific programming language you are having trouble with. In this case, PHP.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking; I think you want to get some difference between two data structures. Could you clearly provide the starting and finishing data structures?

Comment: I want to know if same array is contained in another array. Can you see from my example that array[0] and array[1] contain different combinations of arrays. So if one of the combinations are exactly the same i need to display an error.

Comment: So bottom line, with this array there should not be an error message?

Comment: Yes you are right @Andreas

Comment: Well in that case the example array is pretty useless. Usually when you ask a question you describe the problem and give an example of the problem. Giving an example that works with the code is rather confusing.

Comment: I have changed the array for you. In that case array_diff($arrays[0][0],$arrays[1][0]); should return an empty array which means there are no difference and I should display and error.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the solution.

Here it is:

```
private function validatePossibleConbinations($combinations)
  {
      $error = true;

      foreach($combinations as $set_id => $comb)
      {
          $nextArray = ++$set_id;

          foreach($comb as $key => $selections)
          {
              if(isset($combinations[$nextArray])){

                  foreach($combinations[$nextArray] as $nextComb){

                      if($comb[$key] === $nextComb){

                        $error = false;

                      }

                  }

              }

          }

      }
      return $error;
  }
```